# Play audio in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want my app will play music when she is in the background too,
there is any way to do it? i try to use apple documentation but it didn't work.
it is possible that because i am now using the avplayer i cant play audio in background?

i play the music with

```
ExtAudioFileSeek(mExtAFRef, finalFrames);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think playing audio in background is possible only for streaming audio. For normal audio we can only play when screen is locked.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at documentation of using background tasks like:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

and specially the:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW14

Comment: i already add the Required background modes flag with audio and it is still doesn't work

Comment: so you have to provide more info, about what code do you use, if you§re getting errors, what errors, and so on

Comment: haha :D you must be kidding, what do you think we can do with func call of which we don't know where do you call it, and two variable of which we don't know their types and whatever? Try something better or don't await our help here. sorry