# Playing audio stream in background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm using this code to play a radio stream:

```
NSURL *vibes = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com:8002"];
vPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:vibes];
[vplayer play];
```

Works well while the app is open, but when I go to the background it stops playing. I need it to keep playing in the background like the music app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play audio in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900447/play-audio-in-background)

Comment: have you clicked both links, they are outdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to read up on [Apple's Audio Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875).